# Need to understand why the same function call on two different SQL Servers result in vastly different plans

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2019, functions

I have two SQL Server 2019 instances, one at a customer site and one in our lab. A function call which  determines if an executing trigger is the LAST (or not the LAST) trigger is producing vastly different execution plans at the site and in the lab with vastly different performance. The function call defintion is plagiarized from the web and is based purely on system tables, system calls and ObjectProperty as defined below and NOT on any user defined tables.

[image]
The database schemas on both the instances are exactly the same. Why then would optimizer create two different plans ?
This is the plan from the site
[image]
This is the plan from my lab machine
[image]

The plan xml from the site references several base tables like sysclsobjs,sysschobjs,sysowners,sysclsobjs with really old statistics while the one in the lab does not. Why is the plan referencing these strange tables and does this have any bearing on the performance issue ? Is it possible that the server or database options are slightly different in the lab and at the site ? Any pointers appreciated. I can attach the plan XML and the function definition if that would help

Update 1.

1. [Plan From Site](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkcjK7_Nj)
2. [Plan From Lab](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyXX97OEi)

Comment: Post code as formatted text instead of images. Upload the XML of the actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question as that includes more info than the screenshots. See [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions). Try [updating system table statistics](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-system-table-statistics-update/).

Comment: "*I can attach the plan XML and the function definition if that would help*" - Yes, in addition to what Dan mentioned please. "*why the same function call on two different SQL Servers result in vastly different plans*" - Are the two servers exactly the same in regards to hardware, SQL Server version and edition, same exact data in the databases, and same exact workload?...as these are all factors that can affect the query plan you end up with. From your images the plans don't appear too different but hard to tell without you providing the plans themselves, as there's more info encoded in them.

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the info that comments requested above ^^. With all the details (for both servers). Even one difference between say Standard edition (in customers) and Developer (in lab) may be cause for different plans.

Comment: @DanGuzman, I have attached the links to the plans as Updates to the bottom of my original post. I browse  Brent's site often and did not know about the cool  Paste The Plan feature. I will try updating the site's system table statistics tonight as you suggested and post the response

Comment: @JD, I have attached the links to the plans as Updates to the bottom of my original post. The server versions and editions are the same. Nothing obvious sticks out in the plan but the one from the site takes 250ms to execute whereas in the Lab, it is almost always 0ms.  The schema is the same for both the databases and the function call does not refer to any user defined table.  The hardware & workloads are obviously different at the site and the lab. Is there a reason for asking the question about the workload ? I am currently focusing on the plan as the "root cause".

Comment: @DanGuzman, I was actually able to find an instance in our lab which exhibited the same issue as the site. And I ran your script to update the system table statistics. And the execution plan is now the much improved plan. Thank you. Would you happen to know why a DBA needs to update stats on these system tables ? I do not think this is a widely known fact. Shouldn't the SQL Server be doing this on it's own on these "invisible" tables ? I am at a loss trying to figure out why these go stale on some instances and not on others. Our instances are supposedly built the "exact same way" every time

Answer (score 2):

I would guess your primary issue is actually that you are using the compatibility views such as `sysobjects`, rather than the newer `sys.objects` etc.

The system functions are also a problem when used in a large query, as they can end up getting executed a lot. It's better to just join the correct tables.

You can use the following updated code, which hopefully should give you better performance.

`sysusers` `sys.tables` and `sys.schemas` also don't appear to be doing anything for the query, so I have removed them.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_HasRegularMQTriggerFinishedExecuting (@TriggerId int)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @parent_id int = (
    SELECT tr_other.parent_id
    FROM sys.triggers tr_other
    WHERE tr_other.object_id = @TriggerId
);
  
RETURN CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM sys.triggers tr 
    WHERE tr.is_disabled = 0
      AND tr.parent_id = @parent_id
      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM sys.trigger_events te
        WHERE te.object_id = tr.parent_id
--Filter only for triggers which are not last triggers
        AND te.is_last = 0
      )
      AND TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(tr.parent_id, 'AFTER', 'DML') > 0
  )
  THEN 0
  ELSE 1
  END;

END;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/KROGUd4n)

Comment: @ , Thank you for going the extra mile and rewriting the code. I will try your suggestion next week and provide feedback. Also I wasn't paying attention to the differences between the compatibility view like sysobjects and the new sys.xxx. Thank  you for pointing it out.